# Is there a program that automaticly finds .PHP files on a web server and tests them for SQL injections?

Tags: website, security, sql

I learned about the recent Barracuda hack, which sources say used an automated tool to locate some PHP file and test it for SQL injections.

At my current company, I feel that security is not the top priority and would like to test our websites for SQL injection vulnerabilities.

What tool would you use for such a purpose ? I found out about the python script *sqlmap*, but does it automatically find PHP files used on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlmap` doesn't automatically find the targets, but lets you use proxy logs as source for the target list:

`-l LIST             Parse targets from Burp or WebScarab proxy logs`

Burp homepage: http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html

WebScarab Howto: http://travisaltman.com/webscarab-tutorial-part-1-learning-the-basics/

Of course, you could also log into the server, get a list of php files and modify it to be a valid URL list (if you're not doing complex rewrites on the webserver).

EDIT - Like so, assuming the server runs GNU/Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
uri=http://webapp.yourdomain.com/app/
webroot=/var/www/yourapp/
find $webroot -iname '*php' | sed -e "s#$webroot#$uri#g"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'm worried about forgetting some small php file somewhere, called in Ajax...